# PL/SQL: ORA-01744: inappropriate INTO (2)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
DECLARE 
    OLD_CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(8); 
    NEW_CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(8); 
    T_ENTITY             T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE.ENTITY%TYPE;
    C_CUSTOMER_ID        T_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_BASE.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE;
    T_TEMPLATE_ID        T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE.TEMPLATE_ID%TYPE;
    T_AUTHORIZATIONS     T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE.AUTHORIZATIONS%TYPE;

BEGIN
    OLD_CUSTOMER_ID := '00000081';
    NEW_CUSTOMER_ID := '00000587';

    MERGE INTO T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE TGT
    USING   (
            SELECT  T.ENTITY, C.CUSTOMER_ID, T.TEMPLATE_ID, T.AUTHORIZATIONS 
            INTO    T_ENTITY, C_CUSTOMER_ID, T_TEMPLATE_ID, T_AUTHORIZATIONS
            FROM    T_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_BASE C
            JOIN    T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE T ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T.CUSTOMER_ID
            WHERE   C.CUSTOMER_ID = OLD_CUSTOMER_ID
            ) SRC
    ON  (   TGT.ENTITY          = SRC.ENTITY
        AND TGT.CUSTOMER_ID     = SRC.CUSTOMER_ID
        AND TGT.TEMPLATE_ID     = SRC.TEMPLATE_ID
        )
    WHEN    MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET SRC.AUTHORIZATIONS = TGT.AUTHORIZATIONS
    WHEN    NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (SRC.ENTITY, NEW_CUSTOMER_ID, SRC.TEMPLATE_ID, SRC.AUTHORIZATIONS)
    WHERE   TGT.CUSTOMER_ID = NEW_CUSTOMER_ID;
COMMIT;

END;
```

When running this statement I am getting this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 16, column 13:
PL/SQL: ORA-01744: inappropriate INTO
ORA-06550: line 13, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

What am I doing wrong here? (I tried following instruction here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_variable_types.htm)

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO ...` doesn't make sense within a `MERGE` subquery - what do you expect to end up with in those variables? The 'fix' is to remove that line (line 16, as the error says), and the then-redundant variable declarations - but why were you doing that? If there was a reason - and as you didn't refer to them again there probably wasn't - then we might be able to suggest an alternative. I think you just mixed up two types of syntax though.

Comment: @AlexPoole, as far as I understand, the values in the "SELECT..." will end up in the variables. I tried removing the "INTO..." but then ending up with a {"PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "SRC"."AUTHORIZATIONS": invalid identifier"} error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECT ... INTO` syntax is for putting the results of a query into PL/SQL variables; so you could do this:

```
DECLARE 
    OLD_CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(8); 
    NEW_CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(8); 
    T_ENTITY             T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE.ENTITY%TYPE;
    C_CUSTOMER_ID        T_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_BASE.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE;
    T_TEMPLATE_ID        T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE.TEMPLATE_ID%TYPE;
    T_AUTHORIZATIONS     T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE.AUTHORIZATIONS%TYPE;

BEGIN
    OLD_CUSTOMER_ID := '00000081';
    NEW_CUSTOMER_ID := '00000587';

    SELECT  T.ENTITY, C.CUSTOMER_ID, T.TEMPLATE_ID, T.AUTHORIZATIONS 
    INTO    T_ENTITY, C_CUSTOMER_ID, T_TEMPLATE_ID, T_AUTHORIZATIONS
    FROM    T_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_BASE C
    JOIN    T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE T ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T.CUSTOMER_ID
    WHERE   C.CUSTOMER_ID = OLD_CUSTOMER_ID;

    -- do something with the variables
END;
```

But it is a PL/SQL extension of the `SELECT` statement. You aren't using a `SELECT` statement; you are using a `MERGE` statement which has a subquery - which means that `SELECT` is in a SQL context, not a PL/SQL context, and the PL/SQL extension isn't appropriate or meaningful.

So you can just remove the extra `INTO` clause, and the variables you don't need:

```
DECLARE 
    OLD_CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(8); 
    NEW_CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(8); 

BEGIN
    OLD_CUSTOMER_ID := '00000081';
    NEW_CUSTOMER_ID := '00000587';

    MERGE INTO T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE TGT
    USING   (
            SELECT  T.ENTITY, C.CUSTOMER_ID, T.TEMPLATE_ID, T.AUTHORIZATIONS 
            FROM    T_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_BASE C
            JOIN    T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE T ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T.CUSTOMER_ID
            WHERE   C.CUSTOMER_ID = OLD_CUSTOMER_ID
            ) SRC
    ON  (   TGT.ENTITY          = SRC.ENTITY
        AND TGT.CUSTOMER_ID     = SRC.CUSTOMER_ID
        AND TGT.TEMPLATE_ID     = SRC.TEMPLATE_ID
        )
    WHEN    MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET AUTHORIZATIONS = SRC.AUTHORIZATIONS
    WHEN    NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (SRC.ENTITY, NEW_CUSTOMER_ID, SRC.TEMPLATE_ID, SRC.AUTHORIZATIONS)
    WHERE   TGT.CUSTOMER_ID = NEW_CUSTOMER_ID;
COMMIT;

END;
```

(Not really relevant, but you should be using `VARCHAR2` rather than `VARCHAR` for your variable data types; or `T_CUSTOMER_GRNT_TEMPLATE_BASE.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE`.)

Comment: This is exactly how I had it, but as mentioned before, this gives...

ORA-06550: line 20, column 37:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "SRC"."AUTHORIZATIONS": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error

Comment: @RicoStrydom - you had `UPDATE SET SRC.AUTHORIZATIONS = TGT.AUTHORIZATIONS` - but that's the wrong way around, you should be setting the TGT value to the SRC value. I'm not sure your `WHERE` clause makes sense either - since you know there was no match on TGT.

Comment: now I am getting ORA-38102: Invalid column in the INSERT WHERE Clause: "TGT"."CUSTOMER_ID"

Comment: @RicoStrydom - right, because referring to `TGT` in the *insert* `WHERE` clause doesn't make sense either. You are inserting because there is no match, which means there is no row in `TGT` to refer to. I'm not sure what that clause is suppose to be doing, but you can probably just remove it?

Comment: `ON  (   TGT.ENTITY          = SRC.ENTITY
    AND TGT.CUSTOMER_ID     = SRC.CUSTOMER_ID
    AND TGT.TEMPLATE_ID     = SRC.TEMPLATE_ID
    AND TGT.CUSTOMER_ID     = NEW_CUSTOMER_ID
    )` seem to be doing solving the error but now I wants to insert duplicate rows. Need to do some further digging.

Comment: That `ON` clause can never be matched, if the old and new IDs are different anyway. You're now comparing `TGT.CUSTOMER_ID = SRC.CUSTOMER_ID` (which is, from the subquery, `OLD_CUSTOMER_ID`) *and* `TGT.CUSTOMER_ID = NEW_CUSTOMER_ID`. Those can't both be true at the same time, so you never get a match.

Comment: you are 100% correct. The `AND TGT.CUSTOMER_ID = SRC.CUSTOMER_ID` should not be there. I don't know what I was thinking.  Thanks again.